# WSO2: Override JMS producer JNDI properties for MQ

Tags: wso2, jms, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to override the JMS connection properties as outlined in the documentation:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Using+the+ESB+as+a+JMS+Producer

> You can define a JMS queue name and connection factory parameters in the JMS connection URL. Values of connection factory parameters depend on the type of the JMS broker.

I have multiple queue connection factories defined in my axis2.xml file to support multiple queue managers. However, the following configuration does not take effect (the messages are not sent to the right queue environment):

```
<endpoint name="myEndpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address format="pox" uri="jms://MY_QUEUE_NAME?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=MYQUEUEQCF"/>
</endpoint>
```

The axis2 configuration matches with the above:

```
<transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender">

<parameter name="myConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:bindings</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">OTHERQCF</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false"></parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false"></parameter>
</parameter>

<parameter name="secondConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:bindings</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MYQUEUEQCF</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false"></parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false"></parameter>
</parameter>

</transportSender>
```

The messages are going through the first connection factory, **OTHERQCF**, and not via **MYQUEUEQCF** as expected, so they are sent to the wrong environment. The queue technology used is WebSphere MQ.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I have also tried with the following config and it does not take effect:

```
<endpoint name="myEndpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address format="pox" uri="jms://MY_QUEUE_NAME?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=MYQUEUEQCF&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=file:bindings&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Running on latest EI version 6.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution: the WSO2 documentation is (as usual) incomplete and in this case, incorrect.

First of all, the second JMS producer must have CacheLevel above SESSION (i.e. value set to **auto**, **consumer**, or **producer** in **axis.xml** configuration, e.g.:

```
<parameter name="secondConnectionFactory" locked="false">
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:bindings</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MYQUEUEQCF</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false"></parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false"></parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel" locked="false">producer</parameter>
</parameter>
```

This is because the JMSProducer will otherwise move to use the default connection factory based on the code on github.

Second of all, the documentation states the parameter name incorrectly. The parameter to use is called **transport.jms.ConnectionFactory** and **not transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName**.

Additionally the parameter value is referring to the overall internal **axis2 name of the connection factory, i.e. secondConnectionFactory in the example above**, rather than the MYQUEUEQCF JNDI name.

So with the following configuration, the message is correctly sent to the second queue:

```
<endpoint name="myEndpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address format="pox" uri="jms://MY_QUEUE_NAME?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=secondConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=file:bindings&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it´s the same under EI 6.x but for esb 4.8 you had to define a second transport sender witch you then refer in the send/endpoint.

```
        <transportSender name="jmsSecond" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender">

           <parameter name="secondConnectionFactory" .....

    </transportSender>


<endpoint name="myEndpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address format="pox" uri="jmsSecond://MY_QUEUE_NAME?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=MYQUEUEQCF"/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a bad approach. I would then have 4-5 senders per environment, each with their own bindings file. Additionally it becomes extremely unclear for other developers what is going on when looking through the EPRs and especially in proxy services using the other definitions.

It is possible to define multiple connection factories under the same JMS transport sender/receiver already - that is why they have default and a custom one in their examples. The problem is that the commands after queue name and ? do not take any effect even though they should. This'd be the right way.